# "I am done" or "I have finished" or "I am finished" or "I finish"

Tags: grammar

I was trying to say the following and got bewildered with the different choices.

> I have "To Kill a Mockingbird" on my list. I will write you about it when **I am finished reading it.**
>
> I have "To Kill a Mockingbird" on my list. I will write you about it when **I have finished reading it.**
>
> I have "To Kill a Mockingbird" on my list. I will write you about it when **I am done reading it.**
>
> I have "To Kill a Mockingbird" on my list. I will write you about it when **I finish reading it.**

I am not sure which one to pick. I am confused with the exact meanings of these various choices. Could someone also shed some light on what meanings the different tenses convey in a context like this.

Answer (score 5):

All your four choices are acceptable in daily use. But technically, *cakes are done* and *people are finished*. Also, in proper English usage, *I have finished* is preferred over *I am finished*.

So, in that sense only the following (from your list) are correct:

> I have "To Kill a Mockingbird" on my list. I will write you about it when **I have finished reading it.**
>
> I have "To Kill a Mockingbird" on my list. I will write you about it when **I finish reading it.**

You could also use the following alternatives:

> I have "To Kill a Mockingbird" on my list. I will write you about it when **I finish it**.
>
> I have "To Kill a Mockingbird" on my list. I will write you about it when **I will finish it**.
>
> I have "To Kill a Mockingbird" on my list. I will write you about it when **I am through with it**.
>
> I have "To Kill a Mockingbird" on my list. I will write you about it when **I am through reading it**.
>
> I have "To Kill a Mockingbird" on my list. I will write you about it when **I am through with reading it**.
>
> I have "To Kill a Mockingbird" on my list. I will write you about it when **I complete it**.
>
> I have "To Kill a Mockingbird" on my list. I will write you about it when **I have completed it**.

Also, if what you are writing is not colloquial, you should write *I will write **to** you* instead of *I will write you*.

Comment: I question '. . . when I will finish it'. It's a construction normally found in foreign learners of English.

Comment: Michael Swan's Practical English Usage says that "write to me" is more common than "write me" in standard British English, whereas the latter is standard in American English. Also, I agree with Barry: "will" is not used in time clauses.

Comment: Myself, I would regard *I am through with reading it* as even more colloquial than *I am done reading it*.  At this level, the differences are more regional than grammatical.

Comment: You cannot use future/future in English if–when sentences. So, you cannot say "I will write to you about it when I will finish it. " In this sentence, the first verb is in the simple future (*will write*). Your second verb must be in the present tense. You can use either the present perfect (*have finished*) or present simple (*finish*). Google "English if/when sentences". There are formulas to use that work every time.

Comment: What on Earth does ' But technically, cakes are done and people are finished. ' mean?  How expressions are often used _determines_  their acceptability. And I'm sure that 'I will write you' is acceptable in most registers in the US.

Comment: "I'm finished" describes your state as being 'finished', whereas "I've finished" describes that you have carried out the action of "finishing".